# Associate data with a thread: How do you do that?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

While writing some aysnc controllers in ASP.NET MVC2, I ran up against a situation where I had to call [`AsyncManager.Sync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.async.asyncmanager.sync%28VS.98%29.aspx). It got me wondering:

When I retrieve [`HttpContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx), what's going on? How does ASP.NET know which `HttpContext` I'm after? How is the current context associated with this thread, and how is it retrieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thread scoped storage is used, this is called [Thread Local Storage](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage?wasRedirected=true).

This mechanism allows data to be affinitized with a thread i.e. only the thread that allocates the data sees the data. This is useful for creating so called ambient programming models such as HttpContext.Current and TransactionScope. The mechanism allows data to be accessible at any time on the executing thread without having to "tramp" data through method parameters for instance. It's an elegant solution for certain context\orthogonal problems.

There are number of ways of using TLS including the ThreadStaticAttribute and Thread.SetData\GetData.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After you gave me the keywords (thread local storage), I found a pretty decent article on this (among other things) by Joseph Albahari: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_Thread-Local_Storage

Comment: @spender That's an excerpt from his excellent book. I was going to include that but the section was not linked and was way at the bottom of the page. His threading stuff is very good.

Comment: Funnily enough, it's sitting right here on my shelf. I wonder what other undiscovered gems lie in wait. I'm un-retiring it.